# How to remove method name as the XML root tag in SOAP response

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

I am returning a `XMLDocument` object from my webservice method. In the response I could see the method name as the root element. How to not include that element.

Ex: MethodName is `ValidationMethod` then in the result I am getting `<ValidationMethodResult>` as the root param in the soap body.

I have tried declaring as:

```
(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)
```

It didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

ValidationMethodResult is the class name, not the method name. 
To customize messages, check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkwy2d72(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Dexion, Class name is ValidationServvice , in the XMLResponse I could see the XMLElementAttribute name which I have mentioned at the WebMethodAttribute